# Logistics of Recreating the Michaelson-Morley Experiment

Tags: special-relativity, experimental-physics, home-experiment, aether

I want to recreate the Michaelson-Morley Experiment and am wondering how technically challenging it would be. I'm not looking for it to be super precise, just good enough to provide reasonable confidence that the aether doesn't exist. What would be the logistics involved? Is it something that a couple of college students could put together in a few months for a few hundred dollars?

Although I have a particular fondness for Michaelson-Morley, I am open to performing other seminal experiments that prove more conducive to recreation. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Lasers make it really easy now. And fairly cheap optics are readily available. Most expensive part is temperature control or low expansion base.

Comment: Could you specify how thermal expansion would play a role? Also, if my understanding is correct, we would require some vibrationally-stable way to rotate the setup. Any suggestions for that?